# How freeze Tablix Header in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How to freeze the Tablix header after export to excel from rdl in SSRS.

I am using report builder 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if you set properties to repeat column headers and to
>   keep column headers in view, when you export the report to Excel, the
>   column headers appear at the top of each worksheet and the Freeze
>   Panes feature is enabled for that row.

Found here: [Controlling Row and Column Headings (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240753%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

EDIT: Even though the documentation in the MSDN link above makes it appear that this is possible, further web searches allude that it is not possible to freeze column headers in a tablix when rendered. It can only be done to Report Headers.

Comment: Hi dev_etter, THanks for your reply. But I tries this too. But the report header only freezed not tablix header when I export it to excel.